# How to test high load on a website?

Tags: performance, load-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you load test your application?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/385/how-do-you-load-test-your-application)

Hi,

I am nearing a point of finalizing a website and it will soon be released. We have bought some traffic and advertisement packages and the nature of the site makes it heavier than typical static-like websites. I am looking for hear good ways to test how well the site performs under heavy load.

I already know *ab*. Got any other tips to spare?

Comment: Not a total answer so I just say it as a comment: I heard about testing load with the Amazon Cloud, sounds like something you should look into.