# How to make sure that my web application would be stable?

Tags: performance, load-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you load test your application?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/385/how-do-you-load-test-your-application)

Hi,

I have finished 95% of my web application. Now, I would like to make sure that the website is stable even with 5000 or more concurrent connections.

How do you test??